# What does "the hubris of the defeated" mean?

Tags: meaning, idioms

I saw a movie "A Beautiful Mind".

In the movie, a person said "hubris of the defeated" to a person who lost a game.

In the language I use, it appears to mean "the statement uttered when a person lost a game, battle, etc., and the person is thinking that he should have won, and is frustrated".

Is that a correct interpretation?

I appreciate if the answers were written using basic words.

Comment: I think this is Primarily Opinion-based. For most purposes, *hubris* and *defeated* are disjunctive. The expression has no currency outside the context of the movie, so the meaning is effectively Lit Crit, the same as interpretation of song lyrics/poetry/etc.

Comment: For anyone interested in watching the context: http://www.youtube.com/watch?feature=player_detailpage&v=trn1aO8h9Uo#t=90

Comment: OK, this expression has no currency, I understand.So there is room for much interpretation, isn't there?

Comment: @FumbleFingers they are not disjunctive  (in Greek tragedy) an excess of ambition, pride, etc, ultimately causing the transgressor's ruin

Comment: @Theta30: I think in the "Greek tragedy" context it's more a matter of *pride (hubris) comes before a fall (defeat)*. The two attributes never actually coexist, and they always occur *in that order* (you don't meaningfully still have hubris after the tragic "defeat").

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The proverbial expression is "Pride goes before a fall."

"The hubris of the defeated" is a reference to the overconfidence of someone who is bound to lose, not win.

Comment: Thank you. So I understanded that it is the same meaning as the meaning in the dictionary. OK.